# Activity into List Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview, android-listfragment

Following code is currently working in Activity. But i want to use it for a Fragment and when i tried it is not recognizing my expandable list. If anyone can help me with this would be a great help.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expandable_list);
    createGroupList();
    createCollection();
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.my_exp_list);
    final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(
            this, groupList, laptopCollection);
    expListView.setAdapter(expListAdapter);

    setGroupIndicatorToRight();

    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            final String selected = (String) expListAdapter.getChild(
                    groupPosition, childPosition);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

in my fragment oncreateView,

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_expandable_list, container, false);  createGroupList();
    createCollection();
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) inflater.inflate(R.id.my_exp_list, container, false);
```

Comment: How are you referring to the expandable list in your fragment ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognized" ?
Post the code you used for your Fragment, showing code that works wont help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your are inflating 2 Different Views, or at least trying to. You have to inflate the View, and then get a reference on the ExpandableListView, like this:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_expandable_list, container, false);
createGroupList();
createCollection();
expListView = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_exp_list);
```

as i guess that your Expandable ListView is referenced in the Layout you inflated above, this should work.